# Netbook performance - 1.33 GHz vs 1.6/1.66 GHz Atom

Tags: video, netbook, intel-atom, intel-graphics

All new 11" netbooks seem to carry 1.33 GHz Atom Z520 CPU instead of 1.6/1.66 GHz Atom N270/N280. The screen resolution of 11" netbooks make them very appealing, but I'm a bit concerned about their performance as they carry a slower CPU than the 1.6GHz Atom, which isn't a great performer in the first place.

Is there any significant difference in performance between 1.33 GHz and 1.6/1.66 GHz Atom processors in day to day usage? Are any of those fast enough to decode 720p x264 video? (When paired with typical Intel GMA platform and software decoder like ffdshow/CoreAVC of course, not with Nvidia Ion platform)

Answer (score 2):

I Currenly have a Dell Mini 10 with the 1.33 Atom and GMA500 Graphics.  720p Runs just fine and dandy once you tweak your settings  a bit.  I Use both Ubuntu and Windows 7 with no issues what so ever.  Check mydellmini.com  There are alot of guides Ive written there on how to accomplish this Mainly using ubuntu or a flavor of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried a 1.33GHz yet, so I can't make comparisons, but I can tell you that a 1.6 Atom can decode 720p, but barely, and for some videos you'll need CoreAVC.

Comment: Posting as a comment since it's not part of the answer, but I must state that I'm in no way recommending you buy CoreAVC. I really dislike CoreCodec, so much that I regret giving them $15 for a license a while back.

Comment: If you dislike CoreCodec that much, then you should also tell why :)

Comment: It's just a stupid story between me and their customer support, that would not be a big deal for most people but made me really despise them. And I honestly don't feel like going into it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried 1080p on an Atom 330 (dual core + HT) with CoreAVC and it works pretty well, so I assume 720p will work on it.

I've also read on some forums that the single core, hyperthreaded atoms can play 720p with CoreAVC.

Comment: Wow! I have to buy new Revo then :)